# matplotlib - Allow bar to extend beyond chart limits?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to allow the bar of a bar or barh chart to extend beyond the limits of the chart?

For example, if my data is `np.asarray([1,3,70,924,3])` and I want to limit total height to 300, is it possible without modifying the underlying data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Just set the y-limits of the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,3,70,924,3])

plt.bar(np.arange(data.size), data)
plt.ylim([0, 300])

plt.show()
```

If you want the bar to extend beyond the top of the plot, specify `clip_on=False`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,3,70,924,3])

plt.bar(np.arange(data.size), data, clip_on=False)
plt.ylim([0, 300])

plt.show()
```

[image]